# Why __proto__ is the same

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why different objects have the same **proto** with the same assigned properties?

For example:

```
let a1 = {name: 'firstName'};
let a2 = {name: 'middleName'};
let a3 = Object.assign({}, {name: 'lastName'});

a1.__proto__ === a2.__proto__  // true
a1.__proto__ === a3.__proto__  // true
```

But if I use constructor function:

```
let SomeFunc = function(){}
let b1 = new SomeFunc();
b1.__proto__ === a1.__proto__ // false
The __proto__ is different
```

It looks that all projects created with direct project syntax have the same **proto**.

Comment: All objects have a prototype. For object literals, this is the default `Object` prototype. This should be covered in any book or tutorial on object-oriented programming in JavaScript. Even though it is a bit dated, I recommend the book "The Principles of Object Oriented JavaScript" by Nicholos Zakas (which is both short and unusually readable for a tech book).

Comment: Btw, `__proto__` is deprecated, you should only use `Object.getPrototypeOf(…)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*with the same assigned properties*"?

Comment: What are `bb` and `a1` in the second example? The instance of constrcutor function is called `b1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all the three objects inherit from the same prototype object, `Object.prototype`. That's the default for objects created from object literals.

In your second example, `b1` does inherit from `SomeFunc.prototype`, because it was created with the `new` operator. It would be the same as that of `const b2 = new SomeFunct`: `Object.getPrototypeOf(b2) === Object.getPrototypeOf(b1)`.